# Selecting a LI element from Dropdown

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm having problems with my data driven coded-ui test. I'm supposed to replace the info typed in the test with csv data.

I can succesfully replace login and password inputs with the csv data.. but I'm failing to replace a **selected LI** in the test with it's csv data.

I don't know how to select the LI since it seems to be a custom generated control element but I may be drifting.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur" class="ComboAzul" style="display:inline-block;">
    <table id="cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur_ddlTipoJur_Table" class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphCont$cphContAut$ddlTipoJur$ddlTipoJur_TextBox" id="cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur_ddlTipoJur_TextBox" tabindex="3" autocomplete="off" style="width: 260px; margin: 0px;" type="text">
                </td>
                <td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer">
                    <button style="height: 18px; width: 18px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible;" id="cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur_ddlTipoJur_Button" type="button"></button>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul id="cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur_ddlTipoJur_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 1000; overflow: hidden; width: 310px; position: absolute; height: 133px; left: 638px; top: 425px; display: none;">
        <li style="">&nbsp;</li>
        <li style="">Cons / Ou</li>
        <li style="">Coop</li>
        <li style="">Empr Ind</li>
        <li style="">Req E</li>
        <li>Soc A</li>
        <li>Soc E</li>
    </ul>
    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphCont$cphContAut$ddlTipoJur$ddlTipoJur_HiddenField" id="cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur_ddlTipoJur_HiddenField" value="0" type="hidden">
</div>
```

In the UIMap.Designer.cs the UL ( I believe ) look like this:

```
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.21005.1")]
public class UICphCont_cphConteCustom : HtmlCustom
{

    public UICphCont_cphContCustom(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties["TagName"] = "UL";
        this.SearchProperties["Id"] = "cphCont_cphContAut_ddlTipoJur_ddlTipoJur_OptionList";
        this.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
        this.FilterProperties["Class"] = "ajax__combobox_itemlist";
        this.FilterProperties["ControlDefinition"] = "class=\"ajax__combobox_itemlist\" id=\"cphC";
        this.FilterProperties["TagInstance"] = "1";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Test");
        #endregion
    }
```

Selected LI element looks like this:

```
public HtmlCustom UISocaCustom
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUISocaCustom == null))
                {
                    this.mUISocaCustom = new HtmlCustom(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUISocaCustom.SearchProperties["TagName"] = "LI";
                    this.mUISocaCustom.SearchProperties["Id"] = null;
                    this.mUISocaCustom.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
                    this.mUISocaCustom.FilterProperties["Class"] = null;
                    this.mUISocaCustom.FilterProperties["ControlDefinition"] = null;
                    this.mUISocaCustom.FilterProperties["InnerText"] = "Soc A";
                    this.mUISocaCustom.FilterProperties["TagInstance"] = "6";
                    this.mUISocaCustom.WindowTitles.Add("tEST");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUISocaCustom;
            }
        }
```

The code I'm using to replace the login and password with the csv data is :

```
public void MetdG()
    {
        this.UIMap.TesterParams.UITxtLoginEditText = TestContext.DataRow["login"].ToString();
        this.UIMap.TesterParams.UITxtSenhaEditPassword = Playback.EncryptText(TestContext.DataRow["senha"].ToString());
        this.UIMap.Tester();
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
    }
```

Any idea on how to proceed ?

**Edit : As instructed by [Ryan Cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1885892)**

It was created a static class to hold the browser window :

```
[CodedUITest]
public static class GlobalVars
{
    public static BrowserWindow myWindow;
}
```

Test Initializer method was edited to match this change :

```
[TestInitialize()]
    public void BrowserStarter()
    {
        GlobalVars.myWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("www.google.com"));
    }
```

MainG method was edited so the window could execute the script :

```
 GlobalVars.myWindow.ExecuteScript("var xpath = li[text()='Soca'];var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;);matchingElement.innerHTML = arguments[0];", TestContext.DataRow["type"].ToString());
```

Now the problem is that the script is throwing an exception. I believe it's because it's searching for the element before it exists ( The test goes thru 2 or 3 pages before this point )

Comment: Is the innerHTML of your <li> always "Soc A"?

Comment: In the test it is.. but I have 4 other options that vary depending on the csv column value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is change the inner html on a list item, not enter text as you would in your `<input>` elements, so you'll need to [execute a script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/18/introducing-jscript-execution-on-internetexplorer-and-crossbrowser-in-coded-ui-test.aspx) to do this and modify the DOM.  Since it's not a normal action for a user (click on this, enter text there, expand this combo box, etc.), you'll have to use javascript to complete it.

```
browserWindow.ExecuteScript("var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Soc A") !== -1) {
     elements[i].innerHTML = arguments[0];
     break;
 }
}", TestContext.DataRow["type"].ToString());
//Comment to fill space
```

Of course, if you had an id on your list items, this would be even easier:

```
browserWindow.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById("Soc A list item").innerHTML = arguments[0];", TestContext.DataRow["type"].ToString());
```

Comment: I can't cast it =/ My `csvData` would be -> `TestContext.DataRow["type"].ToString()`

Comment: It throws a casting issue ! Sorry.. I'm new at this.

Comment: Where specifically is the cast failing?  It shouldn't be trying to cast your string into anything differently.

Comment: Also, what is the value type in your csv for that column?

Comment: I'ts throwing this : " An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or propery 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript(string, params object[])"

Comment: All the values in the csv are strings

Comment: Instead of `browserWindow` I typed `BrowserWindow`

Comment: So, `browserWindow` was just a placeholder for the instance of the BrowserWindow in your test.  You'll need to replace that with the object that is instantiated at the beginning of your test.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90548/discussion-between-onilol-and-ryan-cox).

Answer (score 0):

Major props to [Ryan Cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1885892/ryan-cox) for all the help he provided yesterday !

The issue got solved with by adding this line of code :

```
this.UIMap.TestWindow.TestDocument5.UIContCustom.UISocaCustom.
SearchProperties[HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.InnerText] = 
TestContext.DataRow["type"].ToString();
```

Being `TestDocument5` the 5th page in the test ( as intended ), `UIContCustom` the UL element and `UISocaCustom` the custom HTML element the test generated.

It is worth noting that trying to change the value of `InnerText` through `GetProperty` will fail since it will spit out a **read-only** message.